# How to run multi core using jupyter in ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, xeon, linux-server, jupyter-notebook

I have a ubuntu server. it is have a dual xeon E5-2620V4(32 core). The problem is that when running code in "Jupyter notebook", only one of the 32 cores works. So the execution time is very long.

[Image - CPU cores status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbUXY.png)

How can I use all cores?

Comment: Since Jupyter seems to be written mostly in Python, it is hampered by the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) and never really runs as a multi-thread program. And even if using other languages the programs themselves need to be written to run as multi-threaded processes, or split themselves into separate processes.